# Can I mine with CGMiner or BfgMiner with both an AMD and NVidia GPU on the same MOBO?

Tags: gpu, mining-software

I cannot find any good articles or webpages on this, is it possible to run CGMiner with both an AMD and a NVidia graphics card installed? I think I can remember reading something way back that said you shouldn't but can. Does anyone know any concrete information on it?

Comment: What's up with all these people recently wanting to start mining on GPU or even CPU? It's absolutely totally pointless.

Comment: You don't think I know that, there's no need to flame. I would like to mine because I find it enjoyable, its not all about the profit. It is also not pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it´s possible.

But, there are some things that you shound know:

1) Minning Bitcoin with GPU is almost dead, you should have read about other crypto coins. Specifically "scrypt" based ones.

2) Nvidia are not power efficient for mining... would be better if you just sell the nvidia and buy a amd with the same price. Unless you want to use your nvidia for gamming, video editing... dunno... just not for mining.

3) CGMiner = AMD ; CUDAminer = Nvidia ... diferentes programs. don´t no if they work well together... if it does, them you are good to go :-)

hope i had help you.

Comment: The algorithm is scrypt. And yes I know btc gpu mining is dead, I was trying to determine if I could use them for ltc mining. I've got it setup now no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Mining with normal hardware CPU/GPU is pointless you get less than GHs and are not power efficient. Most of the mining pool will not even give you work to do.
You have two alternative, buy hardware: Butterfly labs, Kncminer are the most famous company selling it. In alternative you can use cloud mining with [cex.io](https://cex.io/r/0/giagola/0/) where you can buy and sell GH/s any time. You will get access to the biggest private mining pool, GHash.io and you can potentialy gain on trading

Comment: I am mining ltc, I was just asking in general. Its even more pointless to buy hardware than it is to mine with a gpu.

Comment: Ok I got your point. Although it is not pointless to buy hardware, it is fun and can be economically rewarding.